# I can't recompile im-chooser in Fedora 34

Tags: fedora, xfce, rpm, source

I have a problem in my Fedora 34 with one package which i can't recompile using rpmbuild --rebuild from Fedora 22 to 34, cause it gave me an error which I can't repair.

```
eggsmclient-dbus-gnome.c: In function 'sm_client_gdbus_get_interface_info':
eggsmclient-dbus-gnome.c:80:25: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
 80 |                         g_warning(err->message);
    |                         ^~~~~~~~~
eggsmclient-dbus-gnome.c: In function 'sm_client_dbus_gnome_end_session':
eggsmclient-dbus-gnome.c:123:17: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
123 |                 g_warning(err->message);
    |                 ^~~~~~~~~
eggsmclient-dbus-gnome.c: In function 'egg_sm_client_dbus_gnome_new':
eggsmclient-dbus-gnome.c:163:17: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
163 |                 g_warning(err->message);
    |                 ^~~~~~~~~
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [Makefile:601: libeggsmclient_la-eggsmclient-dbus-gnome.lo] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[2]: Leaving directory '/root/rpmbuild/BUILD/im-chooser-1.6.4/libimchooseui'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:417: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/rpmbuild/BUILD/im-chooser-1.6.4'
make: *** [Makefile:348: all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1):

`g_warning`’s first argument is a format string, and the build in Fedora 34 requires that this be a constant format string (to avoid format string vulnerabilities); patch `eggsmclient-dbus-gnome.c` so that lines 80, 123, and 163 read

```c
g_warning("%s", err->message);
```

You may need to apply the same fix to other calls.

Comment: I changed this line, but now i have a new problem, check edit in my question

Comment: That’s exactly the same problem, with the same solution.

Comment: I changed it for all of lines, but i have the same error, like before.

Comment: ? Can you use im-chooser-1.6.6 ? .... Fedora 23 , 24 update from 1.6.4 to 1.6.6 ~Sep 12 2016. ...... https://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/updates/23/SRPMS/i/im-chooser-1.6.6-1.fc23.src.rpm → `im-chooser-1.6.6-1.fc23.src.rpm` builds in Fedora 34 with no errors.

Comment: If you get exactly the same error, that means you haven’t patched the code correctly; how did you go about it? You need to create a patch file. As Knud suggested, you’d be better off building version 1.6.6.